# Is it ok to turn the mongo ObjectId into a string and use it for URLs?

Tags: mongodb, url, database

```
document/show?id=4cf8ce8a8aad6957ff00005b
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally I think you should be cautious to expose internals (such as DB ids) to the client. The URL can easily be manipulated and the user has possibly access to objects you don't want him to have.

For MongoDB in special, the object ID might even reveal some additional internals (see [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs)), i.e. they aren't completely random. That might be an issue too.

Besides that, I think there's no reason not to use the id.

Comment: So what would you recommend to expose on the client to be able to request a specific object? Would you add another type of id in the BSON object?

Comment: He's saying that if you expose as you did, you could change the letters and get another document that perhaps you're not supposed to. However I don't agree that it's necessarily a bad thing because that's security by obscurity and that's no security at all.

Comment: The ObjectID can tell you when it was created, what machine, which process and in what order. So there is some potential for security risk in exposing this to the public. Some discussion [here](http://www.mongotips.com/b/a-few-objectid-tricks/).

Answer (score 8):

I generally agree with @MartinStettner's reply.  I wanted to add a few points, mostly elaborating what he said.  Yes, a small amount of information is decodeable from the ObjectId.  This is trivially accessible if someone recognizes this as a MongoDB ObjectID.  The two downsides are:

- It might allow someone to guess a different valid ObjectId, and request that object.
- It might reveal info about the record (such as its creation date) or the server that you didn't want someone to have.

The "right" fix for the first item is to implement some sort of real access control: 1) a user has to login with a username and password, 2) the object is associated with that username, 3) the app only serves objects to a user that are associated with that username.

MongoDB doesn't do that itself; you'll have to rely on other means.  Perhaps your web-app framework, and/or some ad-hoc access control list (which itself could be in MongoDB).

But here is a "quick fix" that mostly solves both problems: create some other "id" for the record, based on a large, high-quality random number.

How large does "large" need to be? A 128-bit random number has 3.4 * 10^38 possible values.  So if you have 10,000,000 objects in your database, someone guessing a valid value is a vanishingly small probability: 1 in 3.4 * 10^31.  Not good enough?  Use a 256-bit random number... or higher!

How to represent this number in the document?  You could use a string (encoding the number as hex or base64), or MongoDB's binary type.  (Consult your driver's API docs to figure out how to created a binary object as part of a document.)

While you could add a new field to your document to hold this, then you'd probably also want an index.  So the document size is bigger, and you spend more memory on that index.  Here's what you might not have though of: simply USE that "truly random id" as your documents "_id" field.  Thus the per-document size is only a little higher, and you use the index that you [probably] had there anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I can set both the 128 character session string and other collection document object ids as cookies and when user visits do a asynchronous fetch where I fetch the session, user and account all at once. Instead of fetching the session first and then after fetching user, account. If the session document is valid ill share the user and account documents.

If I do this I'll have to make every single request for a user and account document require the session 128 character session cookie to be fetched too thus making exposing the user and account object id safer. It means if anyone is guessing a user ID or account ID, they also have to guess the 128 string to get any answers from the system.

Another security measure you could do is wrap the id is some salt which you only know the positioning such as
XXX4cf8ce8XXXXa8aad6957fXXXXXXXf00005bXXXX
Now you know exactly how to slice that up to get the ID.