# How to mask/replace Mongo ObjectId in URLs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean.io

Consider an app built, e.g. on the MEAN stack, with urls of type

```
page/number
```

where `number` refers to Mongo ObjectIds. I am aware of the fact that ObjectIds can reveal some information which perhaps shouldn't be available (see [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/), and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345491/is-it-ok-to-turn-the-mongo-objectid-into-a-string-and-use-it-for-urls)).

I wonder is there is some best practice in terms of "hiding" the ObjectId, i.e., having some other value for `number` which 1) allows the app to retrieve the object, and 2) does not carry along the information ObjectIds do.
Alternatively, what is a good way of replacing at all the default ObjectId directly in Mongo documents?

**Note 1**: It can be assumed that the app shows ObjectIds only to authenticated users (e.g., using Passport.js)

**Note 2**: I am aware of other questions here asking similar questions. However, I do not think the issue of masking or replacing default ObjectIds (even to logged users) has been thoroughly discussed (apologies if I am missing something, and feel free to mark the question as redundant).

Comment: If you don't like the default `_id` key as an `ObjectId` then you can always replace it with something else that is unique. This seems like a long winded way of saying "hex values are not very readable". But there are always other ways to do it. It's just a "primary key" selected as the default because of it's "unique" characteristics. If you have something better for your purposes then use it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So, what you suggest is to replace the default ObjectId with another (better) id which does not carry system information along, if I understand correctly. What would be a good replacement?

Comment: Anything "unique" because that is what a "primary key" is used for in any database system. The point is to be "what works best for you", so others really cannot tell you this. The point of an [`ObjectId`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) which is defined as the default for MongoDB is that it has a very "unique" and "monotonic" (ever increasing) concept that scales over multiple server instances, and most especially in that case. If there is some type of "natural" key that defines distinct values to your application, then use that instead.

Comment: @skozz What number? An ObjectId is not a "number" unless you think you are talking about an `_id` field value which can be anything you want it to be. If you have something to add of value then please add it. But don't make people who actually know what they are talking about do work to correct your false statements when you do not.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks again. What is required in order to have an id which "scales over multiple server instances"? Has this anything to do with a component of it representing the physical machine as the default Mongo id?

Comment: Whoa there cowboy. If you are now asking how to produce an `ObjectId` on the client ( i.e "Browser" ) then that is an entirely different question. I advise that you don't do that. And rather refer to the server API to do it for you. That is kind of the intent after all.