# Generating unique Strings for URI (JavaScript/NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ecmascript-6

I'm writing a website, and I want to generate a random link for each article.
I want link to be unique. But also I want to be sure that I can have 100 000 articles with unique links. (I'm using MongoDB - mongoose).
An example link: qw463253qqrASd.
Maximum amount of symbols: 15.

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    url: {type: String, unique: true, default: (() => {
        let gen = "", possible = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm0123456789";
        range(100).forEach((value, index) => gen += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length)));
        return gen;
    })()},
    ...
});
```

P.S.: I do have a function that generates array of numbers.

Comment: "I'm using MongoDB" Why not use ObjectIds then?

Comment: Are they safe for such use?

Comment: [Is it ok to turn the mongo ObjectId into a string and use it for URLs?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4345491/2301450)

Comment: Are there any other options?

Comment: Mongo ObjectIds and UUIDs tend to be too long for a human-friendly URL. Your current solution is on the right track, but understand that you can get away with even shorter strings (i.e. even more human friendly) if you implement retry logic if the identifier already exists in the database. For example, imgur.com used 5-character identifiers for years until they had to move up to 7.

Comment: So I can do human-friendly URL or generate 5 random symbols and as articles amount increases I increment amount of symbols generated, right?

Comment: Yeah, as you get more articles, your retry-logic will spend more and more time retrying since there are more collisions. But that won't happen til you're approaching 1 billion articles which is almost the number of images that imgur.com had when they went from 5 to 7-length identifiers: http://blog.imgur.com/2013/01/18/more-characters-in-filenames/

Comment: You should watch out [with using `Math.random()`](https://medium.com/@betable/tifu-by-using-math-random-f1c308c4fd9d).

Comment: What if I try doing this: http://postimg.org/image/gq6vb87j7/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [mongoose-shortid](https://github.com/jjwchoy/mongoose-shortid) module.

```
var ShortId = require('mongoose-shortid');

var PostSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    url: {
        type    : ShortId,
        len     : 15,
        base    : 62,
        alphabet: '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
        retries : 4, // Four retries on collision
        index   : true
    },
});
```

A few warnings about this module though:

- It it not maintained very actively;
- It currently refuses to work with `mongoose` version 4.x or higher;
- The ids it generates tend to start with one, two or three zeroes.

Maybe there are other, similar modules out there.